# How can I connect localhost of the host machine?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, nginx, reverse-proxy

I was trying to host react as a frontend and rails as backend.

I host rails at http://localhost:3000.

[image]

You can see that it is working.

But when I call http://localhost:3000 from react, instead of going to server's localhost, it go to user's localhost.

[image]

How can I fix this? I am using Nginx as web server.

Comment: The code is upside down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved by doing reverse proxy in Nginx.

```
location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }


location /api {  
 proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; 
}
```

first location / will find static frontend files and /api will go to localhost:3000.

For example, in my case

this.url='https://yourdomain.com/api/' to access the backend.

Also don't forget all of your backend route to start with 'api/'.